# How does Grammarly know where to position the red underline?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, shadow-dom, spell-checking

I've recently become fascinated with how tools like LanguageTool and Grammarly show red underlines on mispelled words on the screen. I'd like to do something similar but to show rich popovers with things like synonyms on hover of a word after first showing an underline on said word.

> This is not about browser extensions. See the links I've included to Grammarly's SDK plugins & LanguageTool's API examples.

I know Grammarly is using the Shadow DOM with slots to wrap the textarea, but I still can't tell how they're able to (efficiently) determine the position of a specific word in the textarea. LanguageTool doesn't use the Shadow DOM.

Neither duplicate show cloned HTML when I inspect it, which I thought they might in order to some how break the text into tokens that they could get bounding rects for -- but that doesn't appear to be it.

The result of using [`<grammarly-editor-plugin><textarea></textarea></grammarly-editor-plugin>`](https://developer.grammarly.com/apps/app_GnSs6MC8fVHfbr1ZN8jDAS/clients/client_CQ9KVT69dvCaS9zxcRtxPQ)
[image]

[LanguageTool example:](https://languagetool.org/)
[image]

I tried using the [Canvas API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript) to get the dimensions of a specific word, but that isn't enough to determine its position in the textarea because the word could be on a line greater than the first.

In order to make this approach work, they have to be getting all the words in the textarea, computing their dimensions, and using the dimensions of the textarea to determine which line a target word is in the textarea; together with the dimensions, specifically the width, of the word, they would then have the x & y positions within the textarea. However, this seems too expensive and slow to pull off as fast as their underlines appear to show.

I could go with contenteditable by just wrapping each word in its own span, but that seems less than ideal.

Does anyone else know how else they could be able to determine the X & Y position of a word in a textarea.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's not a browser extension. I mentioned that and included the HTML they use along with a link to their documentation. Neither of the tools I mentioned are extensions.

Comment: And even if I was referring to extensions, your comment is inaccurate because that's still not how they work. Also, your response and links don't even begin to answer my question on determining positioning.

Comment: That's still not what I'm asking for. My question is very specific and clearly laid out as to what I want to achieve.

Comment: I anwsered the same question like yours in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77299074/22732560)

Answer (score 1):

You got me all fired up but it didn't turn out to be much of a challenge! :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<style>

u{color:red;}

.con{width:500px; height:100px; border:1px solid black;}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<script>

const Correct=['Once','upon','a','time','there','were','three','little','pigs'];


function CheckSpelling(){

var S=Con.innerHTML.replace(/<u\>/g,'').replace(/<\/u\>/g,'');

var A=S.split(' ');

for(let i=0; i<A.length; i++){

 if(Correct.includes(A[i])===false){A[i]='<u>'+A[i]+'</u>';}

} Con.innerHTML=A.join(' ');}


</script>

Change the words below and click spellcheck...<br><br>

<div id="Con" class="con" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true">Once upon a time there were three little pigs</div>

<br>

<button onclick="CheckSpelling();">Check Spelling</button>

<br><br>

NB: Optionally you can automate the spellcheck by adding a oninput="CheckSpelling();" to the container.

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but I specifically mentioned that the scope of the problem is in text areas. At the end of the post, I explicitly mentioned I could use contenteditable, but that's not ideal.

Comment: Nobody uses textareas for such projects, not even for color syntax highlighting! :)

Comment: I guess I'm nobody.

Comment: I also guess Grammarly is nobody.

Comment: Are you saying Grammarly uses a standard HTML textarea?

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, Grammarly uses the [Accessibility API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accessibility) for getting and setting values and properties of controls (selection, text content, character position, caret position, etc.). For changing texts, it  emulates keystrokes. For underlining the text, it uses an overlay window.

I suppose that on MS Windows, it uses equivalent techniques (the [UIAutomation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_winauto/) and overlay windows).

Answer (score 1):

This article from grammarly explain some logic related to their function:

https://www.grammarly.com/blog/engineering/making-grammarly-feel-native-on-every-website/

Which is like what blockwork mentioned, they are using `Reange.getClientRects()`

Answer (score 0):

According to grammarly itself: This can be achieved with the `Range.getClientRects()` API.

https://www.grammarly.com/blog/engineering/making-grammarly-feel-native-on-every-website/

Comment: Your link is pointing to the original question that I ask

Comment: fixed the link: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/engineering/making-grammarly-feel-native-on-every-website/